# SQL Server 2019 DIFFERENCE Function indicates similarity although it's not given

Tags: sql-server, difference

The `DIFFERENCE` function of SQL Server 2019 delivers for two very different strings a value which represents a high level of similarity.

From the documentation:

> DIFFERENCE compares two different SOUNDEX values, and returns an integer value.
> This value measures the degree that the SOUNDEX values match, on a scale of 0 to 4.
> A value of 0 indicates weak or no similarity between the SOUNDEX values;
> 4 indicates strongly similar, or even identically matching, SOUNDEX values.

In my particular case

```
SELECT DIFFERENCE('3CXPhone for Windows', '7-Zip 9.20 (x64 edition)')
```

returns a value of 4.

Is this a common behavior or do I need to consider something further?

Version used:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB4583459) - 15.0.4083.2 (X64)
```

Comment: Looks like [2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c08960b5825aaf5095686a27fd50d887), [2016](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c08960b5825aaf5095686a27fd50d887), [2014](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c08960b5825aaf5095686a27fd50d887) and likely 2012 all return 4.

Comment: This is common behavior. I have not found `SOUNDEX` and `DIFFERENCE` to be particularly useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the Difference function give different results when switching order of strings to compare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347930/why-does-the-difference-function-give-different-results-when-switching-order-of)